# My $link doesn't work in a href='mailto'

Tags: php, html

This is how i get my link

```
$link = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And this is how it looks when i echo it `echo 'My link :  ' . $link;`

http://www.mylink.com/myfile.php?int=&int1=ASD++

But when i put my link in

```
echo "<a href='mailto:$mail&subject=Aktiviteter&body=$link'>Press on the link</a>";
```

I only get

http://www.mylink.com/myfile.php

So i miss my ?int=&int1=ASD++ , how can i get it to? Sorry if im unclear.

Comment: maybe you need to add `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` at the end of your `$link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is being considered part of the string that builds the email.

Your email client is seeing the request as:

```
  subject = Aktiviteter
  body = http://www.mylink.com/myfile.php?int=
  int1 = ASD++
```

Because the email client doesn't know what to do with "int1", it ignores it.

To get around this, you'll want to encode your $link variable into the mailto URL using PHP's [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $link = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    $encoded = urlencode($link);
    echo "<a href='mailto:$mail?subject=Aktiviteter&body=$encoded'>Press on the link</a>";
?>
```

Comment: No worries, you're more than welcome!

You can use this function when you're passing a URL through GET any other time. For example:
$link = 'redirect.php?url=' . urlencode($redirect_url);

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<a href='mailto:$mail?subject=Aktiviteter&body=$link'>Press on the link</a>";
```

after the email address you need to put ? not &

**EDIT**
this shold be the entire script, it works for me...

```
<?php
$mail = 'df@me.com';
$link = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
echo "<a href='mailto:$mail?subject=Aktiviteter&body=$link'>Press on the link</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try string concatenation.

```
echo "<a href='mailto:" . $mail . "?subject=Aktiviteter&body=" . $link . "'>Press on the link</a>";
```

Comment: in this case the script works also without concatenation